# Query on the HHL Algorithm in the Qiskit Aqua Library

Tags: programming, qiskit, resource-request, hhl-algorithm

This is a question regarding the Qiskit Aqua package. I have been studying[image] HHL algorithm from QISKIT textbook and after understanding the math I finally got to the code part, I am having a hard time understanding what is going on. I know how to write code in order to create gates and making a Quantum Circuit, but **I can't find good resources for Aqua. If you guys could point me to some examples or something helpful**, it will be greatly appreciated. I have also posted a screenshot where I got confused.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the tutorials, they are always up-to-date and running:
https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/tree/master/tutorials.
Aqua specific tutorials are e.g. in the chemistry, finance or algorithms subdirectories.

(In fact, this particular example that you posted from the textbook is being refactored, as it is a bit confusing indeed!)

Comment: Thanks, they seem to have a lot of stuff that will be helpful